# Backup Exec 2010 import/export jobs

Tags: windows-server-2008, backupexec

We are in a process of replacing DC and our Backup Exec 2010 is located on it.  I would rather not have to rebuild all the jobs that we have in it now, my question is, is there a way to export them out and import them into newly installed Backup Exec 2010? Or would i have to re-create all the jobs?

Thanks!

Comment: I feel compelled to question the wisdom of installing backup software on a DC and sincerely hope that you're exporting the jobs to recreate them on a dedicated backup sever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be supported.  Symantec tech Support has this.  Info copied to assure a broken link does not result in loss of the information

- Original [here](https://www.veritas.com/support/en_US/article.TECH37072).
- Archive [here](https://archive.is/092NI).
- Dump below.

---

## Copy of TECH37072 content

Copy Media Server Configuration enables a copy of the configuration information for a media server to a configuration file that can be stored on a hard disk location on a network. Using this configuration file, the media server's configuration information can be applied to other media servers with the same version of Backup Exec in an environment.

Configuration information that can be copied includes :

1. Jobs, including backup, restore, and report jobs
2. Policies, templates and selection lists
3. Logon information
4. Media sets
5. Other information such as job defaults, error handling rules, alert configuration, and default schedule data.

Items NOT migrated:

1. Media sets that are not currently assigned to a job.
2. Single instance jobs (i.e. Jobs not scheduled and are set to run only once)

Apply Copied Media Server Configuration:  Enables the media server configuration information—that was copied using the task Copy Media Server Configuration—to be applied to other media servers in the Backup Exec environment.

TO COPY MEDIA SERVER CONFIGURATION TO A FILE (ORIGINAL SERVER):

1. Navigate to the Backup Exec installation directory (:\Program Files\Symantec\Backup Exec) and run BEUtility.exe.
2. Expand Known Media Server and then expand All Media Servers to see the Backup Exec server name on the right.

NOTE: If there are no servers listed, right-click on All Media Servers > select New Media Server > enter the name of the media server and click OK

3. In the right window pane, right-click the Backup Exec media server and select Copy Media Server Configuration.
4. Enter the user name (Domain\User Name ) and password with administrative rights on the Backup Exec server.
5. Browse/Enter the desired location of the configuration file and click OK.
6. Click Close one the Operation Progress window shows completed.

   TO APPLY COPIED MEDIA SERVER CONFIGURATION (NEW SERVER):

   1. Navigate to the Backup Exec installation directory (:\Program Files\Symantec\Backup Exec) and run BEUtility.exe.
7. Expand Known Media Server and then expand All Media Servers to see the Backup Exec server name on the right.

NOTE: If there are no servers listed, right-click on All Media Servers > select New Media Server > enter the name of the media server and click OK.

3. In the right window pane, right-click the Backup Exec media server and select Apply copied media server configuration.
4. Enter the user credentials (Domain\User Name ) and password with administrative rights on the Backup Exec server.
5. Browse/Enter the location of the configuration file which is to be copied and click OK.
6. Click Close on the Operation Progress window when it shows completed.

NOTE: This option is no longer available for Backup Exec 2012.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Roughly, the process is as follows:

Right click the selection list and/or backup job, select "Copy", select the option to "Copy to other media servers", click the "Add" button, type the name or browse for the new server, click OK, click OK.

This will create a job to copy the selection list or backup job to the new server.

One caveat: the job that is created to copy the selection list or backup job to the new server has a built-in, non-adjustable timeout period of about 10 minutes or so. If the copy job cannot be completed within this timeout period the copy job will cancel itself. This can occur with large selection lists and backup jobs based on large selection lists.